# Reassign multiple columns with a single value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is a sample data

```
import pandas as pd
cols = ['Country','Name','SomeNumber','SomeDate']
sourceData  = [('WI','Vivian',34,'#1985-01-01#'),
               ('IND','Sam',56,'#1988-02-01#'),
               ('NZ','Richard',324,'#1987-07-01#'),
               ('AUS','Don',98,'#1998-07-12#'),
               ('SL','Simth',101,'#2001-07-12#'),]
x = pd.DataFrame(sourceData,columns=cols)
x
  Country     Name  SomeNumber      SomeDate
0      WI   Vivian          34  #1985-01-01#
1     IND      Sam          56  #1988-02-01#
2      NZ  Richard         324  #1987-07-01#
3     AUS      Don          98  #1998-07-12#
4      SL    Simth         101  #2001-07-12#
```

What I want to do is, update every column, every value in the table with values missing, except 'Name' columns

Now, update the dataframe should look like this:

```
   Country     Name SomeNumber SomeDate
0  MISSING   Vivian    MISSING  MISSING
1  MISSING      Sam    MISSING  MISSING
2  MISSING  Richard    MISSING  MISSING
3  MISSING      Don    MISSING  MISSING
4  MISSING    Simth    MISSING  MISSING
```

Be advised, I do not want to do something like this considering, in the real world, I have 114 columns:

```
x['Country'] = 'MISSING'
x['SomeNumber'] = 'MISSING'
x['SomeDate'] = 'MISSING'
```

I tried this:

```
cols.remove('Name')
x[cols] = 'MISSING"
```

But it gave me the following warning, which I want to avoid:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#inde
xing-view-versus-copy
  inTardisMissingInSource[cols] = 'MISSING'
C:\tardis\desktop\environment\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:477: SettingWithCopyW
arning:
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `SettingWithCopyWarning` is a good indication that you're using boolean indexing in the wrong place. You should instead use `df.loc`, like this:

```
In [1430]: x.loc[:, x.columns.difference(['Name'])] = 'MISSING'

In [1431]: x
Out[1431]: 
   Country     Name SomeNumber SomeDate
0  MISSING   Vivian    MISSING  MISSING
1  MISSING      Sam    MISSING  MISSING
2  MISSING  Richard    MISSING  MISSING
3  MISSING      Don    MISSING  MISSING
4  MISSING    Simth    MISSING  MISSING
```

The main bit is the `x.columns.difference([...])`. Pass in a list of column headers you want to exclude, and those columns will not be picked up for the assignment.

Note that this mixed assignment will change the `dtype` of the rows, use with caution.

---

If you don't want inplace assignment, you can use `df.assign` by unpacking a dictionary:

```
In [1435]: x.assign(**{ k : 'MISSING' for k in x.columns.difference(['Name'])})
Out[1435]: 
   Country     Name SomeNumber SomeDate
0  MISSING   Vivian    MISSING  MISSING
1  MISSING      Sam    MISSING  MISSING
2  MISSING  Richard    MISSING  MISSING
3  MISSING      Don    MISSING  MISSING
4  MISSING    Simth    MISSING  MISSING
```

Comment: It should be noted that this changes the dtype of the affected columns so if you fill some of the rows later then this will give you columns with mixed dtypes which are problematic

Comment: Very good point, I dont think I'll run into that problem though. COLDSPEED's suggestion does take care of my need

Comment: @EdChum Added a second solution with `df.assign`.

Comment: @PankajSingh this time , the data sample is reproducible~ :) well done

Comment: Semantically it'd make more sense to use `NaN` IMO but I don't know what you're trying to achieve

Comment: @PankajSingh agree with EdChum's suggestion , using `NaN` or `None` for missing value ,

Comment: I am still getting SettingWithCopyWarning warning!!

Comment: @PankajSingh Err, that shouldn't happen. Did you try it with `df.assign` too?

Comment: @PankajSingh The first one should've worked as well. Anyway, do consider marking accepted if you used my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Yes Sir... a super ACCEPTED